# smartmontools - Is the automatic test the same as running a short test?

Tags: centos, smartctl, smart, smartmontools

We're busy setting up smartmontools on our various Linux based servers and although it works, we want to streamline the process a bit. As I understand, we can enable automatic testing which should perform a test each 4 hours, but it does not indicate exactly what test is completed?

Is this test the same as running a short test? We're currently manually doing short tests daily so if the automatic test done each 4 hours is the same I would rather just rely on the automatic testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, these are not equivalent. Automatic testing is just data collection; the short test is an actual test.

This is discussed (at length) in the [`smartctl` manpage](https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/smartmontools/smartctl.8.in), in the section describing the `--offlineauto` settings:

> The  **second**  category of testing is called "offline" testing. This type of test can, in principle,
>                 degrade the device performance.  The `-o on` option causes this offline testing to be carried out,
>                 automatically,  on  a  regular  scheduled  basis.  Normally, the disk will suspend offline testing
>                 while disk accesses are taking place, and then automatically resume it when the disk would  otherwise  be idle, so in practice it has little effect.  Note that a one-time offline test can also be
>                 carried out immediately upon receipt of a user command.  See the `-t offline` option below,  which
>                 causes a one-time offline test to be carried out immediately.

and

> The  **third**  category  of  testing (and the only category for which the word ‘testing’ is really an
>                 appropriate choice) is "self" testing.  This third type of test is  only  performed  (immediately)              when  a command to run it is issued.  The `-t` and `-X` options can be used to carry out and abort
>                 such self-tests; please see below for further details.

So `-t offline` is equivalent to the automatic testing enabled with `-o on`, but that’s not testing, it’s just data collection (it updates the “offline” attributes). The short test, scheduled manually (or using `smartd`), is an actual test, as is the long test; `smartd` comes with example settings enabling nightly short tests and weekly long tests.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen, well answered! I've had some issues with smartd.conf not performing the tests so will setup a cronjob that first ensures offline test data is collected, run a manual daily short test and a long test once a month over weekends.